Document scanner solution for PWA in Blazor
I want to implement the functionality of scanning paper documents via camera into my Blazor PWA.
Something like holding your camera over a document and its edges automaticllay being detected so it can be transformed correctly and saved digitally.
I have tried building it with OpenCVSharp but sadly it is not really working for me at all at this time.
Can anyone recommend any libraries / packages that either implement this functionality or can be helpful while building it?
(paying for a license is not a problem)
Thanks in advance.

you could try this: https://github.com/tony-xlh/BlazorTWAIN
